# GitExtenstions UI blocks clone "server's host key does not match"

Tags: git-extensions

When attempting to clone a repo with Git Extensions and the server's host key has changed the log window reports and error. However the UI doesn't allow answering the prompt. The only thing that can be done at this point is to abort.

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" fetch --progress "origin"
WARNING - POTENTIAL SECURITY BREACH!
The server's host key does not match the one PuTTY has
cached in the registry. This means that either the
server administrator has changed the host key, or you
have actually connected to another computer pretending
to be the server.
The new ssh-ed25519 key fingerprint is:
ssh-ed25519 256 eb:db:****:68:09:48
If you were expecting this change and trust the new key,
enter "y" to update PuTTY's cache and continue connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting but without updating
the cache, enter "n".
If you want to abandon the connection completely, press
Return to cancel. Pressing Return is the ONLY guaranteed
safe choice.
Update cached key? (y/n, Return cancels connection)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 11):

The fix is menu *Repository >> Remote Repositories* and use the [**Test connnection**] button. This brings up the same message and prompt in a console window that can be typed in.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These steps helped me:

1. In git extensions Repository->Remote Repositories->Private Key file:Browse:Choose file
2. Test Connection: failed
3. Close Pageant
4. Test Connection again
5. Press 'save changes' button